# apostrophe in word not being recognized for string replace

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I am having a problem replacing the word *"you're"* with regexp.

All of the other words are changing correctly just the word *"you're"*.
I think it is not parsing after the apostrophe.

I have to replace the word *"you"* to *"I"* and *"you're"* to *"I'm"*.
It will change *"you"* to *"I"* but *"you're"* becomes *"I're"* because it is not going past the apostrophe and it thinks that is the end of the word for some reason. I have to escape the apostrophe somehow.

Please see below for the code in question.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

//Function ElizaResponse to take in and return a string
func ElizaResponse(str string) string {

    //  replace := "How do you know you are"

    /*Regex MatchString function with isolation of the word "father"
    *with a boundry ignore case regex command.
     */
    if matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(`(?i)\bfather\b`, str);
    //Condition to replace the original string if it has the word "father"
    matched {
        return "Why don’t you tell me more about your father?"
    }
    r1 := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)\bI'?\s*a?m\b`)

    //Match the words "I am" and capture for replacement
    matched := r1.MatchString(str)

    //condition if "I am" is matched
    if matched {

        capturedString := r1.ReplaceAllString(str, "$1")
        boundaries := regexp.MustCompile(`\b`)
        tokens := boundaries.Split(capturedString, -1)

        // List the reflections.
        reflections := [][]string{
            {`I`, `you`},
            {`you're`, `I'm`},
            {`your`, `my`},
            {`me`, `you`},
            {`you`, `I`},
            {`my`, `your`},
        }

        // Loop through each token, reflecting it if there's a match.
        for i, token := range tokens {
            for _, reflection := range reflections {
                if matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(reflection[0], token); matched {
                    tokens[i] = reflection[1]
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        // Put the tokens back together.
        return strings.Join(tokens, ``)

    }

    //Get random number from the length of the array of random struct
    //an array of strings for the random response
    response := []string{"I’m not sure what you’re trying to say. Could you explain it to me?",
        "How does that make you feel?",
        "Why do you say that?"}
    //Return a random index of the array
    return response[rand.Intn(len(response))]

}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())

    fmt.Println("Im supposed to just take what you're saying at face value?")
    fmt.Println(ElizaResponse("Im supposed to just take what you're saying at face value?"))


}
```

Comment: Note that your exemplar text contains curly apostrophes while your regular expressions contain only the single prime (what you actually get when you press the single quote key without some kind of "smart quotes" feature as you'd find in a word processor).

Comment: Note the `r1` pattern does not contain any capturing groups, when you replace with `$1`, you just remove the match. So, `capturedString := r1.ReplaceAllString(str, "$1")` = `capturedString := r1.ReplaceAllString(str, "")`. I understand it is not the most important part of the code, but please make sure you understand what it is doing.

Comment: I am going to replace that when i have the first problem done. It is replaceing "I am , I'm, Im" all case ignored. i have the sentence to concatenate to it after i have the word You're changing correctly.

Comment: Ok, see [this demo](https://play.golang.org/p/8vfxiouDSC). Sorry, I am in a rush, but you will get the gist.

Comment: Thank you  Wiktor Stribiżew That is a great solution. I have found that i just need to change the regular expression to the boundaries variable. I''l Post my solution below. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 5):

Note that the apostrophe character creates a word boundary, so your use of `\b` in regular expressions is probably tripping you up.  That is, the string `"I'm"` has four word boundaries, one before and after each character.

```html
┏━┳━┳━┓
┃I┃'┃m┃
┗━┻━┻━┛
│ │ │ └─ end of line creates a word boundary
│ │ └─── after punctuation character creates a word boundary
│ └───── before punctuation character creates a word boundary
└─────── start of line creates a word boundary
```

There is no way to change the behavior of the word boundary metacharacter so you might be better off mapping regexes that include the full word with punctuation to the desired replacement, e.g.:

```
type Replacement struct {
  rgx *regexp.Regexp
  rpl string
}

replacements := []Replacement{
  {regexp.MustCompile("\\bI\\b"), "you"},
  {regexp.MustCompile("\\byou're\\b"), "I'm"},
  // etc...
}
```

Note also that one of your examples contains a UTF-8 "right single quotation mark" (U+2019, 0xe28099), not to be confused with the UTF-8/ASCII apostrophe (U+0027, 0x27)!

```
fmt.Sprintf("% x", []byte("'’")) // => "27 e2 80 99"
```

Comment: thank you for your response maerics
I can see what you are saying but i just need to replace you're with I'm.

Comment: Sorry posted too early :) is There a way to escape the apostrophe and force regex to consider it as one word?

Comment: I think the split function is also splitting it into separate words as well because of the boundaries := regexp.MustCompile(`\b`).

Comment: The result of fmt.Println(tokens) is: [  supposed   to   just   take   what   you ' re   saying   at   face   value ?]
 supposed to just take what I're saying at face value?

Comment: Is there a condition i can put in there to ignore putting a boundary after the u and the '

Comment: @user2963022 no, there is no way to change the behavior of the word boundary metacharacter.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve here is to replace specific strings with specific replacements. It is easier to achieve that with a map of string keys and values, where each unique key is a literal phrase to search and the values are the texts to replace with.

This how you may define the *reflections*:

```
reflections := map[string]string{
    `you're`: `I'm`,
    `your`: `my`,
    `me`: `you`,
    `you`: `I`,
    `my`: `your`,
    `I` : `you`,
}
```

Next, you need to get the keys *in the descending by length order* (here is [a sample code](https://gobyexample.com/sorting-by-functions)):

```
type ByLenDesc []string
func (a ByLenDesc) Len() int {
   return len(a)
}
func (a ByLenDesc) Less(i, j int) bool {
   return len(a[i]) > len(a[j])
}
func (a ByLenDesc) Swap(i, j int) {
   a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}
```

And then in the function:

```
var keys []string
for key, _ := range reflections {
    keys = append(keys, key)
}
sort.Sort(ByLenDesc(keys))
```

Then build the pattern:

```
pat := "\\b(" + strings.Join(keys, `|`) + ")\\b"
// fmt.Println(pat) // => \b(you're|your|you|me|my|I)\b
```

The pattern matches `you're`, `your`, `you`, `me`, `my`, or `I` as whole words.

```
res := regexp.MustCompile(pat).ReplaceAllStringFunc(capturedString, func(m string) string {
    return reflections[m]
})
```

The above code creates a regex object and replaces all matches with the corresponding `reflections` values.

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/AVCpfotSqP).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that i just needed to change these two lines of code.

```
boundaries := regexp.MustCompile(`(\b[^\w']|$)`)
return strings.Join(tokens, ` `)
```

Its stops the split function from splitting at the ' character.
Then the return of tokens needs a space to put out the string otherwise it would be a continuous string.